# Disable "The build directory needs to be at the same level as the source directory" warning in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a Qt project located in the folder `/Users/donaldduck/OneDrive/Documents/myproject`, and I want to have the build directory as a subfolder of the source directory, at `/Users/donaldduck/OneDrive/Documents/myproject/build-myproject`. The problem is that Qt Creator gives me a warning saying "The build directory needs to be at the same level as the source directory":

[image]

Other than this warning, the project compiles just fine. I don't even get any problems that the build directory is a subfolder of the source directory. I searched on the web to see why I get this warning, and I found that it's probably because not having the build directory at the same level as the source directory could cause problems with relative paths. But I don't have any relative paths in my program, I have all of the files in a QRC resource.

So this error is just annoying, and I would like to disable it. I've searched the web for a solution, but haven't found anything.

Also, I only get this warning on my Windows computer and on my Mac virtual machine. I have a similar folder structure (the build directory is a subfolder of the source directory) on my Linux virtual machine, but none of them give any warning. Also, before I updated Qt on Windows, I didn't get that warning, but since I updated it I've been getting this warning on Windows also.

How can I disable this warning?

Comment: Generally speaking, you will want to do it the recommended way. Source directory ideally contains only files under version control. Easiest is just to use the build directory Qt Creator suggests. Why do you want to change the default behavior? Is there an actual problem you want to solve by having build dir under source dir instead of beside it?

Comment: Also note that typically you have at least two build directories, one for Debug and one for Release builds. If you target more platforms, or want different build options for different versions, then you may have arbitrary number of build directories. So it's better to talk about "build directories" in plural...

Comment: Prepare the build directory in OSX environment as http://osxdaily.com/2015/08/06/make-symbolic-links-command-line-mac-os-x/ and point the physical location anywhere you like but refer to the symlink in Qt Creator. Just a bit unsure of "Mac Virtual Machine" then and if that is available from there.

Comment: Also, the warning comes from *qmake* I believe. *qmake* is actually run in the build directory, and given relative path to the source directory. There probably are some default assumptions, which may break if build directory is actually under source directory in some cases, hence the warning. But I'm not sure, so not writing this as an answer.

Comment: @hyde I want to do it that way because otherwise my Documents folder would be a bit messy since I would have (at least) 3 different folders in there: one for the sources, one for the debug build and one for the release build. I think it's better to put the build directories inside the source directory, so that I only have one folder in the Documents folder for the whole project so that everything is at the same place. And I do have several build directories, but I didn't mention it to not bother you with details. I actually have six build directories, two for each OS.

Comment: You can suppress this warning by patching Qt Creator.

Comment: The warning is annoying, but the build seems to work for me.  As to 'why do this ?' - I specify a build directory in /dev/shm.  That is a RAM based directory.  I get a faster build and I reduce the writes to my SSD.

Answer (score 8):

Disabling not possible but the solution is to change build directory.

This warning does show if the source- and the build directory do not contain the same **number** of `/` (or `\` on windows) in their absolute path names.

Assuming your source directory is "c:\dev\source\project", then "..\build-directory" is fine, but e.g. "..\build\directory" is not. "c:\dev\build\project\debug" is not ok, but "c:\dev\build\project-debug" is. "./debug" and "debug" are not ok as build directories either.

Is what you can observe as well? Or are all paths starting with "..\" triggering this warning?

Qmake will fail to build projects that are not following the "same distance from root" rule in some rare corner cases and will produce really cryptic output when it does. So we need to warn about a setup like this.

you can use your default directory like this: `../%{CurrentBuild:Name}`

Screenshot: [image]

I use this directory: `../Build/Windows/%{CurrentBuild:Name}` and I don't care about the warning!

Reference: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16616

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old but since the versions of Qt have evolved a bit since then, I allow myself to post this answer to best help those who would be confronted with this problem on **Qt Creator 9.0.1** :)
I set up this architecture (in my documents) to separate my sources "Projets_Qt" from my builds "Projets_Qt_Builds".
[image]

Then under Qt Creator I went to the "Edit" menu then "Preferences" and "Build & Run"
In the "General" tab I filled in "**Project Directory**" the folder of my sources "C:\Users\juan\Documents\**Projets_Qt**"
[image]

In the "**Default Build Properties**" tab I filled in "Default build directory" the folder of my builds "../../**Projets_Qt_Builds**/%{JS: Util.asciify("build-%{Proj... ...". It's a relative path built from the sources actually
[image]

**Think about it** :
If you perform this operation while projects have already been created, do not forget to modify the project in question.
Once your project is open, use the "Projects" menu in the right icon bar, then in the desired kit modify "Build Directory"
[image]

Hope this information can help :)